# How do crossbow traps work?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What kind of attack does a weapon trap with only crossbows use? Does it use bolts, and if so, which ones? Or does it only use the melee bash attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weapon traps with ranged weapons are exactly like weapon traps with anything else - when the trap is triggered, the weapon attacks.

Ranged Weapon Traps specifically, however, *do* require ammo and need to be reset, same as Stonefall and Cage Traps (but with **bolts** rather than stones or cages). They'll use whatever bolts your mechanic can get their hands on, so you might want to forbid certain bolts / use burrows if you'd rather the trap be loaded with a specific batch.

Comment: So a crossbow trap can be loaded with more than one bolt? Is it possible to see how many bolts are loaded into the trap?

Comment: Yes, It's one stack, I think. I've never used them recently, so I can't tell you any more precise than that.

Comment: After a little test, it seems that more than one stack of bolts can be loaded into a trap: http://i.imgur.com/a9Vvy.png I have yet to determine if there is a maximum number of bolts that can be loaded into a trap (I ran out of bolts). It is the mechanic labour that is used to load the traps.

Comment: @jaminja it looks like your dwarves are loading one crossbow bolt at a time, too.

Comment: those are just bolts that have been fired at my dwarves by goblin invaders and then collected individually. I've made some more bolts now, which were loaded into the trap in stacks of 5, and it looks like 5 stacks of bolts can be loaded into the trap.

Comment: "when the trap is triggered" - triggered by stepping on it? At least I think that's how weapon traps are triggered. But aren't crossbow traps long range? :(

Comment: @Annan not in dwarf fortress